# bet365 login request

Tags: python, authentication, http-authentication

I'm trying to make a script for logging in [bet365](https://mobile.bet365.it/).  I'm suspended on the login. The params of POST requests are:

```
LOGIN_URL = "https://mobile.bet365.it/"
{
   DeviceId : "..."
   Platform : "..."
   txtPassword: "..."
   tktTKN: "..."
   txtType: "..."
   txtUsername: "..."
}
```

So I composed this `payload` to try to access the login page:

```
payload = {
    "txtUsername": UTENTE,
    "txtPassword": PASSWORD,
    "txtTKN": authenticity_token,
    "platform": platform,
    "txtType": txtType
}
LOGIN_URL = "https://mobile.bet365.it/"
result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))
```

I'm completely sure that this values are correct(except platform and txtType because I didn't understand what they are so I copied the value that always were set when I logged in). 
But then, if I try to check if I'm logged in, I realize that I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome tells me the login page to post to is this page:

https://mobile.bet365.it/members/lp/default.aspx

Why do you think it's the URL you list?

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference?

Comment: "https://mobile.bet365.it/" vs "https://mobile.bet365.it/members/lp/default.aspx". Yes?

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that no evident "login failed" messages where present in the login page)
Usually the fact that you are logged in is "saved" in 1 or more cookies (*sessionID), so what I would do is look for them in the response of the "login request" and add them to the following requests.

There's a snippet from some code of mine to give you the general idea

```
import httplib2
headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'accept-encoding': "identity", ...
        }
payload = { ... }
http_client = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http_client.request(
                    login_url,
                    "POST",
                    urllib.urlencode(payload),
                    headers)
# ...
cookie = response.get("set-cookie")
if cookie:
    headers['Cookie'] = cookie  
# ...
 response, content = http_client.request(
                    other_url,
                    "POST",
                    urllib.urlencode(payload),
                    headers)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what replace with "..." in accept-encoding and in comment. However it display me  `http_client = http.Http()
NameError: name 'http' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, if it's misleading, I've used "..." to say "some other stuff", I was trying to give the general idea: I have a dict with some headers I needed in order to do the request and that afterwards I add an another element to this dict( the cookie I've got after the first request). Also, it doesn't mean that you have to use exactly those headers, I would try adding pretty much the same headers I could see in a request done by the browser (go "dev tools" (f12) then "network" tab and search for your request).

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the typo, I've fixed it now. If you don't have `httplib2` installed, look in the library you are using now for something that could help you replicate the "main" idea: "look for cookies in the responses, make sure they are passed to the following requests.